# CodeIgniter .htaccess links

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter

I am new to codeIgniter and .htaccess stuff.
I already made to remove the index.php to `localhost/ci/index.php/site/home`.
So my home page can access now to `localhost/ci` or `localhost/ci/site/home`.

I have

```
<a href="home">Home</a> and <a href="about">About</a>
```

I can access Home and About if I Am on this link `localhost/ci/site/home`.
But once I'm on `localhost/ci` the problem exists because when I click to `<a href="about">About</a>` the site is redirecting me to `localhost/ci/about` instead of `localhost/ci/site/about`. I change the links to `<a href="site/home">Home</a> and <a href="site/about">About</a>` the browser keeps adding the `/site` every click like
`localhost/ci/site/site/site/site/site/site/home`

Anyone can help me to fix the problem?

.htaccess

```
 <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /ci

#Removes access to the system folder by users.
#Additionally this will allow you to create a System.php controller,
#previously this would not have been possible.
#'system' can be replaced if you have renamed your system folder.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

#When your application folder isn't in the system folder
#This snippet prevents user access to the application folder
#Submitted by: Fabdrol
#Rename 'application' to your applications folder name.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^application.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

#Checks to see if the user is attempting to access a valid file,
#such as an image or css document, if this isn't true it sends the
#request to index.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]

</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
    # If we don't have mod_rewrite installed, all 404's
    # can be sent to index.php, and everything works as normal.
    # Submitted by: ElliotHaughin

ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at the [URL Helper](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/url_helper.html)? It has many functions which will help in these situations.

First make sure you load the helper either in your Controller or [autoload](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/autoloader.html) configuration.

**anchor()**

The `anchor()` helper would be ideal in this instance. e.g.

```
<?php echo anchor('home', 'Home'); ?>
```

**base_url()**

Or alternatively you could build up the href using `base_url` as previously mention.

```
<a href=<?php echo base_url(); ?>"about">About</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Go to your config file and set `index_page` to be empty.
This will remove the index.php

and when you write links set `/` infront as :

```
<a href="/home">Home</a> and <a href="/about">About</a>
```

Comment: index_page is already empty.
<a href="/home">Home</a> and <a href="/about">About</a>
Will send me to
localhost/home not localhost/ci/site/home
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

what @Svetlio said + i advise you to use `site_url()` when creating links

Comment: why not using this in comment section if you are talking about someone like Svetlio ??

Comment: i don't know why, sometimes i have a comments link, sometimes not, that's why. for this comment i have an add comment, for svetlio i still don't have one.

Answer (score 0):

You're re-adding the main controller even though the htaccess is set to see that as the base. Writing your links as follows should fix the issue.

```
<a href="about">About</a>
```

The other way around it is to run off the base at all times, which isn't really necessary but can work if you're having issues otherwise.

```
<a href=<?php echo base_url(); ?>"about">About</a>
```

What that is going to do is echo out whatever you have set as the base URL in your config every time you write a link so if your base_url in your config is www.localhost.com the above will write www.localhost.com/about.

Don't worry you'll get the hang of it, the routing is probably the most complicated part of CI when you first start.

Comment: Fatal error: Call to undefined function base_url()
I am getting that error.
<a href=<?php echo base_url(); ?>"about">About</a>
How to write that?

Comment: Make sure you load the URL Helper class

Comment: Yep, and to be honest this is one of those helpers you want to load in your autoload.php in your config folder

Answer (score 0):

`<a href="<?php echo base_url('home') ?>">Home</a>`

`<a href="<?php echo base_url('about') ?>">About</a>`